# Determining how many messages are on the Azure Service Bus Queue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-queues, azure-servicebus-queues

I know there is a way to determine the number of messages (or approximate number) in the Azure Queue (Store Account); however is there a way to query for the number of pending messages on an Azure *Service Bus* queue?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283583/azure-service-bus-queue-count

Answer (score 32):

```cs
var nsmgr = Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
long count = nsmgr.GetQueue(queueName).MessageCount;
```

Comment: With the new `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` library, this is done a little differently. You can see how it's done in the [ManagementUnitTests#GetQueueRuntimeInfoTest()](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/blob/master/test/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.UnitTests/Management/ManagementClientTests.cs#L262).

Comment: I'm using .net core. nuget Microsoft.ServiceBus do not have NamespaceManager

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury You've saved my life today. Thank you

Comment: This is no longer the best answer in 2022 - for the newer Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus library [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72543295/5740181) is most up-to-date.

Answer (score 19):

**Correct answer as of 2020+**

Use of new packages as follows:

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="x.x.x" />
```

also two namespaces in the same package

```
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration;
```

and then you can use the new class ServiceBusAdministrationClient

```
var administrationClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient("connectionString");
var props = await administrationClient.GetQueueRuntimePropertiesAsync("queue");
var messageCount = props.Value.ActiveMessageCount;
```

Comment: This answer should really now be the accepted one given that Microsoft now recommends devs use the "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" package and not the older "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" package which **depreciated in Nov 2020**.

Comment: This is the answer for 2022

Comment: @aceinthehole please mark this answer as the correct answer - the previous library still needs dot net framework - which is not supported in the latest versions.

Answer (score 12):

It is called MessagesCountDetails.ActiveMessageCount.
It returns the number of the **Active Messages** in the Queue. You probably have some Dead letter messages:

```
var msg = Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
numofmessages.Text = msg.GetQueue(QueueName).MessageCountDetails.ActiveMessageCount.ToString();
```

Comment: That child-object (MessageCountDetails) was hiding all the goodies!  Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QueueDescription qd = nsm.GetQueue(qName);
int x = 0;
x = qd.MessageCountDetails.ActiveMessageCount;
x = qd.MessageCountDetails.DeadLetterMessageCount;
x = qd.MessageCountDetails.ScheduledMessageCount;
x = qd.MessageCountDetails.TransferDeadLetterMessageCount;
x = qd.MessageCountDetails.TransferMessageCount;

Comment: I'm using .net core. nuget Microsoft.ServiceBus do not have NamespaceManager

Answer (score 7):

have you looked at the [Queue Description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh780773.aspx) API? There's a property called `MessageCount`.

Here's the [.NET SDK reference documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.messagecount.aspx) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Based off what Joseph had as an answer I came up with, but for Topics and Subscriptions.

```
public async Task<long> GetCounterMessages()
        {
            var client = new ManagementClient(ServiceBusConnectionString);    
            var subs = await client.GetSubscriptionRuntimeInfoAsync(TopicName, SubscriptionName);
            var countForThisSubscription = subs.MessageCount;  //// (Comes back as a Long.)               
            return countForThisSubscription;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem trying to get the count from the dead letter queue. It looks like the deadletterqueue doesn't allow you to get a count directly, you get it from the MessageCountDetails of the normal Queue.

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Microsoft.ServiceBus.Connstr"].ToString();
NamespaceManager nsmgr = Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
return nsmgr.GetQueue(QueueName).MessageCountDetails.DeadLetterMessageCount;
```

Comment: I'm using .net core. nuget Microsoft.ServiceBus do not have NamespaceManager

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PowerShell example to continually eyeball the queue length as used in Azure Portal Cloud Shell

```
cd "Azure:\<MySubscription>\"
while (1) {(Get-AzureRmServiceBusQueue -ResourceGroup <myRG> -NamespaceName <myNS> -QueueName <myQueueName>).CountDetails | Select -expand ActiveMessageCount}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've spent good 2 hours digging through docs to get that and for people using .net core and Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus nuget package, code looks like that:

```
var managementClient = new ManagementClient("queue connection string"));
var runtimeInfo = await managementClient.GetQueueRuntimeInfoAsync("queueName");

var messagesInQueueCount = runtimeInfo.MessageCountDetails.ActiveMessageCount;
```

Aparently you get the information about all Counts(including deadletter, active, etc.) from QueueRuntimeInfo object instead of  old QueueDescription object.

Answer (score 0):

As per the recommendation by Microsoft, it is recommended to use Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus in which you can easily fetch the message count by

```
var managementClient = new ManagementClient("connection string for queue");
var queue = await managementClient.GetQueueRuntimeInfoAsync("queue name");
var messages = queue.MessageCount;
```

Answer (score -3):

Also..you can check the pending messages on Azure Management Portal...on the dashboard for service bus queue...under quick glance...you can see the queue length...this is the number of current/pending messages in length at the time of dashboard page load.

Comment: You can also use the service bus explorer in Visual Studio (if you have it) to view the properties of each entity for a namespace.