# Azure Service Bus Queue Count

Tags: azure, servicebus

I have a service bus Q and from the Azure portal I can more or less see how many entries the service bus Q contains. How can I get this count using their management API? I have perused the docs but have been unsuccessful in finding an answer.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254951/determining-how-many-messages-are-on-the-azure-service-bus-queue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The QueueDescription has a property MessageCount: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.messagecount.aspx), [Announcement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj737688.aspx) (skip down to Message Count Details)
This will allow access via .NET code

The Management API Documentation also shows this exposed: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh780773.aspx)
This will allow access via the Rest API

The PowerShell Cmdlets do not yet expose this functionality.