# .NetCore Azure Servicebus get current message count

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azureservicebus

The old method of getting count from Queue was like this:

```
 CloudQueue q = queueClient.GetQueueReference(QUEUE_NAME);
            q.FetchAttributes();
            qCnt = q.ApproximateMessageCount;
```

This no longer works with .netCore with AMQP 1.0

I am not finding a good way to get a message count. Any ideas on what I am missing ?

Comment: This doesn't look Azure Service Bus code snippet, but Storage queues.

Comment: Sure, what is the equivalent function for getting the number of items in Queue in ServiceBus ?

Comment: Google "azure service bus queue get message count" and literally the very first result is a SO answer to your question :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254951/determining-how-many-messages-are-on-the-azure-service-bus-queue

Comment: The example you quote above applies to storage queues not servicebus, the answer below is the right one as it explains you need to get an oauth token to get the count.

Comment: I'm sorry mate, but you have to read a bit closer. Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager is not storage queues, but the Full .NET framework client for ASB. There are multiple ways to skin a cat: .NET Framework client using Namespace manager or Management library with AAD. You need a token if you go through AAD. If you have a connection string (containing SAS token), you don't need the AAD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus Libary that is a **preview** version, is 100% compatible .Netcore. We can get more [detail](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus/) here.

**Preparetion:**

[Registry Azure Active Directory application and assign Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application)

**Steps:**

Create a .net core console project and add the following code.

```
 var tenantId = "tenantid";
            var context = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/{tenantId}");
            var clientId = "Client";
            var clientSecret = "Secret";
            var subscriptionId = "subscriptionId";
            var result =  context.AcquireTokenAsync(
                "https://management.core.windows.net/",
                new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret)).Result;

            var creds = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);
            var sbClient = new ServiceBusManagementClient(creds)
            {
                SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
            };
            var queueParams = new QueueCreateOrUpdateParameters()
            {
                Location = "East Asia",
                EnablePartitioning = true
            };
           
            var queue = sbClient.Queues.ListAll("groupname", "namespace").ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("queuename")); 
            var messagecount = queue.MessageCount;
```

[image]

From Azure poratal, we check the message in the queue

[image]

Project.json file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus": "0.2.0-preview",
    "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory": "3.13.9",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The above worked. For anyone else who stumbles upon this, groupname is your Resourcegroup name and NameSpace is the Queue Namespace.

Comment: I am sending messages to the queue like this 
 queueClient = new QueueClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, QueueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
                // Create a new brokered message to send to the queue
                var message = new Message($"Message {precheckMessage}");
                // Send the message to the queue
                await queueClient.SendAsync(message);
Is there an easy way to get the QueueID when I push the message ? Like a context ?

Comment: If using above code, we can get queueid easy `var queue = sbClient.Queues.ListAll("groupname", "namespace").ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("queuename"));`  `var id = queue.id` then we can get queue id as  **/subscriptions/subscriptionId/resourceGroups/resource groupname/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/servicebusname/queues/queuename**