# Determining how many messages are on the Azure Service Bus Queue for a specific SessionId

Tags: azure, servicebus, azure-queues

I have a servicebus queue that contains messages with different session ids.
Is there a way to get the message count for a specific session id?

Comment: Any solution? is it even possible?

Comment: @AryanFirouzian No real solution at this moment. Aa a workaround all the messages from the session are retrieved and counted to get the total number.

Comment: Did you get the solution for this? I'm searching for a solution to the same problem, thanks

Comment: @Juan No solution at the moment, still using the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the count of messages held in queues and subscriptions by using Azure Resource Manager and the Service Bus NamespaceManager APIs in the .NET Framework SDK as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-counters).
You can also refer the suggestions provided by the community members [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254951/determining-how-many-messages-are-on-the-azure-service-bus-queue). See if this helps you.

Comment: I believe this is the message count for the entire queue not for a specific session.